# creating a private ethereum blockchain network for private application use

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Im wondering if its possible to create a private ethereum blockchain network to use for my application. I need a ledger system to keep track of user account balances and I think this is the most secure way. Any guides or explanations on how? I see a couple of articles on medium but they are stating it is a  “test” network. I would need this to be used in production, of course, i do not mean in the main ethereum network but in my private network solely for my app.

Comment: Have you thought about using a DB? Maybe easier in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Here is explained how you can start [private Ethereum network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network).